# Draw simple text with metal

Tags: swift, metal, metalkit

In our app, we used metal to draw heart rate graph and it works fine, but now I want to draw a simple text with metal.

Since I wasn't part of the team when they implemented metal calculation. I have a few questions:

**1-** In the metal view encoder, should I use `line drawPrimitives type` ? I mean `drawPrimitives` use to draw an object, right? so I have to use it for draw text as well?

**2-** We use a custom class to create a circle Vertex, now my question is, should I use a something like this class to draw words in a text?

**3-** And my final question, is what is the easiest way to draw and render a simple text (this text is an integer, something like : 1250) in swift.

many thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1)** You can use any of these data types. It depends on your implementation, the most frequently used types are `MLPrimitiveTypeTriangle` or `MTLPrimitiveTypeTriangleStrip`.

**2)** You can use any class you want to create vertex, the important thing is to ensure that it conforms with **Metal** rules.

**3)** The fastest way to draw text on Metal is to use **SpriteKit framework**. SpriteKit contains a class named `SKRenderer` that allows an app to mix SpriteKit and Metal content by rendering an SKScene into a Metal command buffer.

Comment: Thank you so much, I really appreciate it.  May I ask you to help me on number 2 - create a class to draw 3-4 digit numbers